# DevExtreme Turkish character issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mobile, devextreme

I'm developing a mobile application on DevExtreme with AngularJs. I want to use several character like (ş,ı,ç,ö,ü,ğ), but became a issue.I wrote these characters in title toolbar with $scope but, it didn't work. I have chanced the language attribute in `<html>` with `<tr>`, but it didn't work.
Can you help me? [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nQPf.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide a working sample that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I have chanced attribute from File -> Advanced Save Options to Turkish(Pagecode 1254). Then Application worked fine.